# I am using kyeup function with CodeIgniter but kyeup function is not workin fine

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter

I am using kyeup function with CodeIgniter on modals but result not show . javaScript working first time alert  msg  but secound time return response msg not show . I am sharing code "HTML ,javaScript ,controllers ,models" please share valuable idea sir...

**HTML**

```
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pran_no" id="pran_no" required="">
     <div id="msg"> </div>//error mag not show
```

**JavaScript**

```
    <script>    

        $(document).ready(function()
          {
          $('#pran_no').keyup(function()
             {
             var pran_no = $('#pran_no').val();

                //alert(pran_no);here working fine

                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>pran_no_exist",
                data: "pran_no="+pran_no,                     
                success: function(response)
                   {

                   //alert(response);//here not show error

                   $('#msg').html(response);
                  }
               });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

**controllers**

```
function pran_no_exist()
        {
         $result = $this->Cms_model->pran_no_exist();
          //echo $result;   
         }
```

**models**

```
    public function pran_no_exist() { 
            $pran_no = $this->input->post('pran_no');
            $this->db->select('pran_no');
            $this->db->from('users');
            $this->db->where('pran_no',$pran_no);
            $querya = $this->db->get();
          if ($querya->num_rows() > 0)  
            {
             echo '<p style="color:red;">Already Existing Pran No.</p>';
            }else {
                 echo '<p style="color:green;">Not Existing Pran No.</p>';
            }

          }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Javascript**

```
<script>    

        $(document).ready(function()
          {
          $('#pran_no').keyup(function()
             {
             var pran_no = $('#pran_no').val();

                //alert(pran_no);here working fine

                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>pran_no_exist",
                data: {'pran_no':pran_no},                     
                success: function(response)
                   {

                   //alert(response);//here not show error

                   $('#msg').html(response);
                  }
               });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

**Controller**

```
function pran_no_exist() {
  $pran_no = $this->input->post('pran_no');
  $result = $this->Cms_model->pran_no_exist($pran_no);
  if ($result) {
   if ($result->num_rows() > 0)  
   {
     echo '<p style="color:red;">Already Existing Pran No.</p>';
   }else {
     echo '<p style="color:green;">Not Existing Pran No.</p>';
   }
  }
}
```

**Model**

```
public function pran_no_exist($pran_no) { 
  $this->db->select('pran_no');
  $this->db->from('users');
  $this->db->where('pran_no',$pran_no);
  return $this->db->get();
}
```

Comment: i have need return msg

Comment: @Amit I have edited my answer. I think it will work now

Comment: @Amit check it the network tab for error when to press the key.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change keyup to input change :

Javascript:

```
 <script>    

            $(document).ready(function()
              {
              $('#pran_no').keyup(function()
                 {
                 var pran_no = $('#pran_no').val();

                    //alert(pran_no);here working fine

                    $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>pran_no_exist",
                    data: {pran_no:pran_no},                     
                    success: function(response)
                       {

                      var result = JSON.parse(response);
                         if(result == null)
                           {alert("Not Existing Pran No.");}
else{ alert("alread existing");
}
                      }
                   });
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Controller:

```
  function pran_no_exist() {
        $result = $this->Cms_model->pran_no_exist($_POST["pran_no"]);
echo json_encode($result); 
    }
```

Model Code:

```
public function pran_no_exist($pran_no) { 
  $this->db->select('pran_no');
  $this->db->from('users');
  $this->db->where('pran_no',$pran_no);
  $querya = $this->db->get()->row();
   return $querya;

}
```

Comment: but you didn't get write answer for your query is right?

Comment: try to change : data: pran_no: pran_no,

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'baseurl path',
    data: { 
        'foo': 'bar'
    },
    success: function(msg){
        alert('wow' + msg);
    }
});
```

Comment: hey man! your ajax request method is wrong try to pass data as an array i post the sample code in answer section